# How to define a type of a bit-combination?

Tags: powershell, types, bit-manipulation

I am struggling with Powershell to create a custom type that has a bit-combination like file-attributes. The usage of the type should work later like this:

```
$attr = [myType]::new()
$attr.read = $true
$attr.write = $true
$attr.execute = $true
write-host $attr # or $attr.toString()? -> read,write,execute
write-host $attr.value__ # -> 7 (3 bits set to 1)
```

My final type will need 6 bits. I want to skip the part with manual bit-operations in my later code to get each bit back. So, I want to have it in the type, if possible. Any ideas how to get this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you might use the PowerShell [Enumerations as flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_enum#enumerations-as-flags) feature:

> ### Enumerations as flags
>
> Enumerations can be defined as a collection of bit flags. Where, at any given point the enumeration represents one or more of those flags turned on.
>
> For enumerations as flags to work properly, each label should have a power of two value.

#### Example specific to your question

In the following example the **Access** enumeration is created

```
[Flags()] enum Access {
    Execute = 1
    Write = 2
    Read = 4
}
```

Taking advantage of the PowerShell implicit type casting where generally the left-hand-side of the operator dictates the type casting of the right-hand-side (respecting the operator precedence) you might use the flag `enum` as follows:

**Assigning**

To assign bits (flags) to the `[Access]` type, you might use a simple string array:

```
$Access = [Access]'Read', 'Execute'
```

Or as commented by [**@mklement0**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0), use a single string:

```
$Access = [Access]'Read, Execute'
```

**Reading**

To read (and/or display) the assigned access:

```
$Access
Execute, Read

[int]$Access
5
```

**Setting**

To set a bit (flag) of the `[Access]` type, you might use the binary or (`-bor`) operator:

```
$Access -bor 'Write'
Execute, Write, Read
```

**Resetting**

To reset a bit (flag) of the `[Access]` type, you might use the binary and (`-band`) and a binary invertor (`-bnot`) operator:

```
$Access -band -bnot [Access]'Read'
Execute
```

<sup>(note that you will need to explicitly set the type for RHS of the `-not` operator)</sup>

**Testing**

To test that a specific bit is set, you can use the binary comparison operator `-band`. In this example, we test for the `[Access]` attributes in the value of `$Access`.

```
If ($Access -band 'Read') { 'You have read access' }
'You have read access'
```

As noted by **@mclayton** this will not work for multiple flags in once:

```
$Access -band ([Access]'read, write')
Read
```

Returns `Read` which implicitly casts to `$True`, see: [Booleans\Converting from collection types](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_booleans#converting-from-collection-types).
In other words, if you want to make sure that all concerned bits (flags) are set in the `$Access` Value, you probably want to use the `HasFlag` method instead:

```
$Access.HasFlag([Access]'read, write')
False
```

Thank you [**@mklement0**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) for the list of notable enum-relevant GitHub issues (as of PowerShell 7.4.0-preview.3):

- [Bug: enum-typed parameters inappropriately accept multiple values even for non-flag types](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19513)
- [Bug: Defining a custom enum with a negative value bypasses validation on cast / assignment](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7286)
- [Suggestion: During method overload resolution, give precedence to enum overloads when given string arguments](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13161)
- [Suggestion: Tab completion for assignment of flag-based enum values to variables](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13161)
- [Suggestion: Custom-class and enum type literals are not recognized by tab completion](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7287)

Comment: Note the pattern to test for *multiple* flags is  ```if( ($access -band $desired) -eq $desired)```, or more simply ```if( $access.HasFlag($desired) )```, otherwise you risk getting a false positive - e.g. ```$access = [access] "read, write";
$desired = [access] "read, execute"; write-host [(bool] ($access -band $desired));
Write-host $access.HasFlag($desired)``` - the first is ```$true``` but the second is ```$false```…

Comment: Thanks, @iRon and Santiago. In addition to mclayton's suggestion, I suggest also mentioning the _single-string_ option (`[Access] 'Read, Execute'`), as an alternative to the _array_ option (`[Access] 'Read', 'Execute'`) you're already showing.

Comment: A list of notable `enum`-relevant GitHub issues (as of PowerShell 7.4.0-preview.3): * [Bug: enum-typed parameters inappropriately accept *multiple* values even for non-flag types](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19513)
* [Bug: Defining a custom enum with a negative value bypasses validation on cast / assignment](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7286)
* [Suggestion: During method overload resolution, give precedence to enum overloads when given string arguments](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13161)

Comment: *  [Suggestion: Tab completion for assignment of flag-based enum values to variables](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10647)
*  [Suggestion: Custom-class and enum type literals are not recognized by tab completion](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7287)