# How to create a Converter for an Enum

Tags: powershell, enums, typeconverter

How to create (preferably in PowerShell) a type converter for a custom PowerShell [`[enum]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_enum)?

Related PowerShell issue: [`enum <enum-name>` should ConvertFrom `[string]`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19625)

Based on the specific `[Access]` example in question [How to define a type of a bit-combination?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76189035/1701026):

```
[Flags()] enum Access {
    Execute = 1
    Write = 2
    Read = 4
}
```

I am trying to build an `[Access]` `ConvertFrom` converter:

```
class AccessConverter : System.Management.Automation.PSTypeConverter
{
    [bool] CanConvertFrom([object]$sourceValue, [Type]$destinationType) {
        return $sourceValue -eq [string]
    }
    [object] ConvertFrom([object]$sourceValue, [Type]$destinationType, [IFormatProvider]$formatProvider, [bool]$ignoreCase) {
        if     ($sourceValue -eq [string]) { return [Access]$SourceValue }
        else { throw [NotImplementedException]::new() }
    }
    [bool] CanConvertTo([object]$sourceValue, [Type]$destinationType) {
        return $false
    }
    [object] ConvertTo([object]$sourceValue, [Type]$destinationType, [IFormatProvider]$formatProvider, [bool]$ignoreCase) {
        throw [NotImplementedException]::new() 
    }
}

Update-TypeData -TypeName Access -TypeConverter AccessConverter
```

But that doesn't work as expected:

```
$Access.HasFlag('read, write')
```

> MethodException: Cannot convert argument "flag", with value: "read, write", for "HasFlag" to type "System.Enum": "Cannot convert value "read, write" to type "System.Enum". Error: "Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true.""

Or is that because [`HasFlag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag?view=net-8.0) expects a general `enumType` type rather then the specific custom ("`access`") `enum`?

Comment: "Or is that because HasFlag expects a general enumType type" - yes, exactly that - `HasFlag`'s only parameter is typed `Enum`, it isn't specific enough for PowerShell to know to invoke the converter. `$Access.HasFlag([Access]'read, write')`

Comment: @Mathias, thanks for this definition. Could the `HasFlag` method technically be more specific than it is now? (I don't think it should just accept any `[enum]` but only it's own enum). In other words, is it worth to create a `.Net` feature request (rather then a  PowerShell) for this?

Comment: I'm guessing there's probably a good reason a generic version of `HasFlag` hasn't been added since it was introduced ~15 years ago - but I honestly don't know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this would work with a `PSTypeConverter` or if it even relates, what you're looking to accomplish, as I see it, can be achieved by overriding the `.HasFlag` method from your `enum` with a script method that casts your type:

```bash
[Flags()] enum Access {
    Execute = 1
    Write = 2
    Read = 4
}

$updateTypeDataSplat = @{
    TypeName   = 'Access'
    MemberType = 'ScriptMethod'
    MemberName = 'HasFlag'
    Value      = {
        param([Access] $flag)

        $this.PSBase.HasFlag($flag)
    }
}

Update-TypeData @updateTypeDataSplat

$access = [Access] 'Execute, Read'
$access.HasFlag('Execute, Read')         # true
$access.HasFlag('Execute, Write, Read')  # false
```

Comment: Thanks, I was actually looking for an understanding of what I was trying to do with regards to a Type Converter but this indeed does fulfill the wishful thinking prototype idea.

Comment: @iRon as I understand it, `PSTypeConverter` is useful when you want to convert one type to the type you implement by for example casting, but that doesn't mean that all the methods (`HasFlag` in this case) will also attempt that conversion.