# How can I “add” a list of binary options and then decode them at a later time?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

I know there are plenty of ways to do this with built-in functions for most languages, but I always thought this was a nifty trick to use when passing in options to functions, so please don’t suggest using built-ins.  I’m not even suggesting this is a good programming practice, but it’s been gnawing at me for years.

So the idea is we’re going to pass in a single value parameter $myOptions which is going to contain an integer value representing multiple on/off binary values.  And we might add new options later, of course we don’t know what those will be.  So each option might be represented as follows:

```
mFoo = 1
mBar = 2
mFoobar = 4
mFubar = 8
mPhoobar = 16
mPhubar = 32
```

As you might recognize, each “option” is represented by an option’s ordinal position *raised* to the power of two.

- In position 0 `mFoo` = (2<sup>0</sup>) = 1
- In position 1 `mBar` = (2<sup>1</sup>) = 2
- In position 2 `mFoobar` = (2<sup>2</sup>) = 4
- In position 3 `mFubar` = (2<sup>3</sup>) = 8
- In position 4 `mPhoobar` = (2<sup>4</sup>) = 16
- In position 5 `mPhubar` = (2<sup>5</sup>) = 32

It should be obvious what the next option, should you choose to add one would be.  Now one can easily add these values together, depending on what options you want to have “on” and then decode the options selected when needed.  e.g. let’s say you want to call a function and pass in every option as “being on” **except** for `mFubar`.  So 1+2+4+16+32=55.

Here’s the part I keep forgetting.  How do I “decode” this number to see if a particular option is on or off?  Trial and error leads me to believe you use the **bitwise and** operator.  In C# that would be `&`.  So if you wanted to see if mFubar is “on” you would check to see if

```
(55 & mFubar) != 0
```

And 55 & 8 *evaluates* to 0, so we know `mFubar` was not passed in as “on”.  Similarly we can use this operation on the other options, like `mPhoobar` which is 16, and we would see that (55 & 16) evaluates to 16, which *is decidedly not zero* so we know that option `mPhoobar` was indeed set to “be on”.

My question is, am I missing something?  IIRC this was easy and difficult at the same time.  With the advent of OOP having to deal with this sort of “option handling” is kind of a Stone Age programming relic.  But back in the day when memory, disk space, and everything in between were expensive, every character mattered.

Comment: A few CLR methods do use this approach; it's what [the `Flags` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=net-7.0) for enums is for. The only thing you're really missing is the fact that you can use the [`Enum.HasFlag()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag?view=net-7.0) method to test if the flag is set, which might make it more readable.

Comment: Why did you tag [tag:PowerShell]?

Comment: If it does actually concerns PowerShell, does this answer your question: [How to define a type of a bit-combination?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76189035/1701026)?

Comment: Just an addition to the previous comments: if this is a C# question, then you can use the bit shift operator for the powers of 2 in your `enum` decorated by the `[Flags]` attribute to improve readability, especially for higher values. For example: `mPhubar = 1 << 5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Reinventing the Wheel

This is all a bit unnecessary since dotnet and PowerShell have useful features like [`FlagsAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=net-7.0) and [`Enum.HasFlag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag?view=net-7.0) built in, but since you specifically said:

> please don’t suggest using built-ins

...here's a CS101 on bitmasks :-)

---

### Bitmasks

What you're talking about is called a "bitmask" - it's a lot easier to explain if you work in binary rather than decimal:

```
$mFoo     = 0b000001  # 2^0 =  1
#                  ^

$mBar     = 0b000010  # 2^1 =  2
#                 ^

$mFoobar  = 0b000100  # 2^2 =  4
#                ^

$mFubar   = 0b001000  # 2^3 =  8
#               ^

$mPhoobar = 0b010000  # 2^4 = 16
#              ^

$mPhubar  = 0b100000  # 2^5 = 32
#             ^
```

where the `0b` prefix indicates a binary literal:

[about_Numeric_Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-7.3#integer-literals)

> #### Integer Literals
>
> Integer literals can be written in decimal, hexadecimal, or binary notation. Hexadecimal literals are prefixed with 0x and **binary literals are prefixed with 0b** to distinguish them from decimal numbers.

If you look carefully, each value is represented by a bit in a unique column being set to `1` and all other bits set to `0`.

### Setting Bits

To set bits in a bitmask you simply set the values in the appropriate columns to `1` - your example of

> "every option as 'being on' except for `$mFubar`. So 1+2+4+16+32=55"

would be:

```
  0b000001  #  1
+ 0b000010  #  2
+ 0b000100  #  4
+ 0b010000  # 16
+ 0b100000  # 32
  --------
  0b110111  # 55
```

Although I've used **addition** above, it's safer to do a boolean (binary) "or" to set bits because the one you're "adding" might already be set:

```
$myVariable = ???

# WRONG - what if $mFoo is already set? (e.g. $myVariable = 0b000001)
# in that case, we'd now have accidentally set the $mBar bit instead:
#
#   0b000000 ($mFoo not set) + 0b000001 ($mFoo set) => 0b000001 ($mFoo set)
#   0b000001 ($mFoo set)     + 0b000001 ($mFoo set) => 0b000010 ($mBar set)
#                                                                ^^^^^
$myVariable = $myVariable + $mFoo

# RIGHT - if $mFoo is already set the $mFoo bit remains unchanged:
#
#   0b000000 ($mFoo not set) -bor 0b000001 ($mFoo set) => 0b000001 ($mFoo set)
#   0b000001 ($mFoo set)     -bor 0b000001 ($mFoo set) => 0b000001 ($mFoo set)
#
$myVariable = $myVariable -bor $mFoo
```

so the example above would be:

```
$value = $mFoo -bor $mBar -bor $mFoobar -bor $mPhoobar -bor $mPhubar
# 55
```

Note that `-bor` will also correctly combine values that have multiple bits set:

```
$x = $mFoo -bor $mBar -bor $mFoobar # 7

$y = $mFoo -bor $mBar -bor $mPhubar # 35

# WRONG - don't add bitmasks
$x + $y    # 42 -> 0b101010 -> $mPhubar, $mFubar, $mBar set

# RIGHT - binary "or" bitmasks
$x -bor $y # 39 -> 0b100111 -> $mPhubar, $mFoobar, $mBar, $mFoo set
```

### Testing Bits

Now we know how to *set* bits in bitmasks we want to be able to determine if a bit is set.

You suggested:

```
(55 -band $mFubar) -ne 0
```

which works for *single* bits, but if you want to test a combination of bits this returns `$true` if any single one of the bits is set:

```
$value = $mFoo -bor $mBar -bor $mFoobar # 7

# note - only $mFoo is set on $value
$test  = $mFoo -bor $mPhubar

# tests if *any* of the bits that are set in $test are set in $value
($value -band $test) -ne 0
# True
```

If you want to test if *both* bits are set you need to do this instead:

```
$value = $mFoo -bor $mBar -bor $mFoobar # 7

# note - only $mFoo is set on $value
$test  = $mFoo -bor $mPhubar

# $mPhubar isn't set, so not *all* the bits that are
# set in $test are set in $value
($value -band $test) -eq $test
# False
```

And then let's set `$mPhubar` and try again:

```
$test = $test -bor $mPhubar

($value -band $test) -eq $test
# True
```

Both ways (i.e. `($value -band $test) -ne 0` and `($value -band $test) -eq $test`) are fine - which one to use just depends on what you're actually trying to test.

### Unsetting Bits

To unset a bit you might be tempted to subtract, but that would be wrong for the same reason as adding is wrong for setting a bit:

```
$myVariable = ???

# WRONG - what if $mFoo is already unset? (e.g. $myVariable = 0b000010)
# in that case, we'd now have accidentally unset the $mBar bit instead:
#
#   0b000011 ($mBar, $mFoo set) - 0b000001 ($mFoo set) = 0b000010 ($mBar set)
#   0b000010 ($mBar set)        - 0b000001 ($mFoo set) = 0b000001 ($mFoo set)
#                                                                  ^^^^^
#
$myVariable = $myVariable - $mFoo
```

It's a *little* bit more complicated to unset a bit, but not much:

```
# RIGHT - if $mFoo is already unset we don't subtract it again
#
#   0b000010 ($mBar set)        => 0b000010 ($mBar set)
#   0b000011 ($mBar, $mFoo set) => 0b000010 ($mBar set)
#
$myVariable = $myVariable - ($myVariable -band $mFoo)
```

Happily, this also works for multiple bits set in a value:

```
$value = $mFoo -bor $mBar -bor $mFoobar -bor $mPhoobar -bor $mPhubar
# 55

$unset = $mFoo -bor $mFoobar

$value - ($value -band $unset)
# 50 ($mBar, $mPhoobar, $mPhubar set)
```

### Library

Since you don't want to use built-ins, here's a quick set of functions that wrap all the above. You could turn them into advanced functions and take `$Bits` values from the pipeline if you were inclined...

```
function Set-Bits
{
    param( [uint] $Value, [uint[]] $Bits )
    foreach( $Item in $Bits )
    {
        $Value = $Value -bor $Item
    }
    return $Value
}

function Test-AnyBit
{
    param( [uint] $Value, [uint] $Bits )
    return ($Value -band $Bits) -ne 0   
}

function Test-AllBits
{
    param( [uint] $Value, [uint] $Bits )
    return ($Value -band $Bits) -eq $Bits
}

function Unset-Bits
{
    param( [uint] $Value, [uint[]] $Bits )
    foreach( $Item in $Bits )
    {
        $Value = $Value - ($Value -band $Item)
    }
    return $Value
}
```

Examples:

```
PS> $value = Set-Bits -Value 0 -Bits $mFoo, $mBar, $mFoobar, $mPhoobar, $mPhubar
# 55

PS> Test-AnyBit -Value $value -Bits $mFoo, $mBar
# True

PS> $value = Unset-Bits -Value $value -Bits $mFoo
# 54

PS> Test-AllBits -Value $value -Bits $mFoo, $mBar
# False
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an Enum with the [Flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute) attribute and use [Enum.HasFlag(Enum) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag) to see if a particular flag is set.